# Connection Errors in Using DB2 and Redis Images as a Service into CI/CD Gitlab Pipeline

Tags: java, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, db2

I am having the next .gitlab-ci.yml file in which I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline by using DB2 and Redis images as a service, create the appropriate containers from them and then execute the tests of my Java application.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - test

variables:
  UCD_WEB_URL: "https://my.url.gr:8443"
  UCD_COMPONENT_NAME: "my-project-name"
  JSON_IMPORT_CONTENT: '{"component": "$UCD_COMPONENT_NAME", "properties": {"version": "$APP_VERSION"}}'

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - export APP_VERSION="$(grep '^version' ./gradle.properties | cut -d= -f2)-$CI_PIPELINE_IID"
  - export GRADLE_PARAMETERS="various parameters"

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/caches

build-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Building...."
    - gradle build -x test --info $GRADLE_PARAMETERS
    - echo "END of Build...."
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*
    expire_in: 1 day

integration-tests-job:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: ibmcom/db2:11.5.5.0
      alias: db2
      variables:
        DBURL: "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/CDH"
        DBDRIVER: "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
        DBNAME: "MYDB"
        LICENSE: "accept"
    - name: redis:7.2.1
      alias: redis
      entrypoint: [ "redis-server" ]
      command: [ "--requirepass", "password" ]
      variables:
        REDIS_PASSWORD: "password"
        REDIS_PORT: 6379
        REDIS_HOST: redis
        REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
  script:
    - sleep 180
    - echo "Starting execution of integration tests...."
    - gradle libertyStart --info $GRADLE_PARAMETERS
    - sleep 30
    - gradle test --info ${GRADLE_PARAMETERS//-Pprofile=uat/-Pprofile=dev}
    - echo "Execution of integration tests finished...."
```

However, after pushing in my Gitlab repository, I am receiving the following error:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.25.13] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server localhost/127.0.0.1 on port 50,000 with message: Connection refused. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

**STEPS DONE SO FAR**

1. Registered images ibmcom/db2:11.5.5.0 and redis:7.2.1 into GitLab runner.
2. Used `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` feature flag to run services with Podman as an executor.
3. The application is running on host machine. For this reason I tried both `localhost` and the `127.0.0.1` IP address.
4. Usernames and passwords are defined in the `before_script` section under `GRADLE_PARAMETERS`. These parameters are registered as variables in CI/CD settings of Gitlab.
5. At the above file I use `sleep` to give some time for DB2 to be up and running. I also tried to write the below script for fetching the logs of DB2 container.

```
- |
      DB2_CONTAINER_ID=$(docker ps | grep "ibmcom/db2:11.5.5.0" | awk '{print $1}')
      echo "Fetching DB2 logs for debugging:"
      docker logs $DB2_CONTAINER_ID
```

However, I received the next error:

> /bin/sh: eval: line 143: docker: not found

which indicates that the Docker command-line interface (CLI) is not available in the environment where the GitLab runner is executing the job. Unfortunately I don't have access to the config.toml file of my GitLab runner, as of now.

6. After further research, I found out that the DB2 needed extra privileges. So I reached the team that manages the runner and they added `privileged = true` into `config.toml`. After this approach the following errors appeared:

> SQL1032N No start database manager command was issued

> SQL1042C An unexpected system error occurred

> SQL1031N The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system

Currently, I am in confusion about what I am doing wrong. Any help and suggestions are much appreciated.

I am having the next .gitlab-ci.yml file in which I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline by using DB2 and Redis images as a service, create the appropriate containers from them and then execute the tests of my Java application.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - test

variables:
  UCD_WEB_URL: "https://my.url.gr:8443"
  UCD_COMPONENT_NAME: "my-project-name"
  JSON_IMPORT_CONTENT: '{"component": "$UCD_COMPONENT_NAME", "properties": {"version": "$APP_VERSION"}}'

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - export APP_VERSION="$(grep '^version' ./gradle.properties | cut -d= -f2)-$CI_PIPELINE_IID"
  - export GRADLE_PARAMETERS="various parameters"

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/caches

build-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Building...."
    - gradle build -x test --info $GRADLE_PARAMETERS
    - echo "END of Build...."
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*
    expire_in: 1 day

integration-tests-job:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: ibmcom/db2:11.5.5.0
      alias: db2
      variables:
        DBURL: "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/CDH"
        DBDRIVER: "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
        DBNAME: "MYDB"
        LICENSE: "accept"
    - name: redis:7.2.1
      alias: redis
      entrypoint: [ "redis-server" ]
      command: [ "--requirepass", "password" ]
      variables:
        REDIS_PASSWORD: "password"
        REDIS_PORT: 6379
        REDIS_HOST: redis
        REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
  script:
    - sleep 180
    - echo "Starting execution of integration tests...."
    - gradle libertyStart --info $GRADLE_PARAMETERS
    - sleep 30
    - gradle test --info ${GRADLE_PARAMETERS//-Pprofile=uat/-Pprofile=dev}
    - echo "Execution of integration tests finished...."
```

However, after pushing in my Gitlab repository, I am receiving the following error:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.25.13] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server localhost/127.0.0.1 on port 50,000 with message: Connection refused. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

**STEPS DONE SO FAR**

1. Registered images ibmcom/db2:11.5.5.0 and redis:7.2.1 into GitLab runner.
2. Used `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` feature flag to run services with Podman as an executor.
3. The application is running on host machine. For this reason I tried both `localhost` and the `127.0.0.1` IP address.
4. Usernames and passwords are defined in the `before_script` section under `GRADLE_PARAMETERS`. These parameters are registered as variables in CI/CD settings of Gitlab.
5. At the above file I use `sleep` to give some time for DB2 to be up and running. I also tried to write the below script for fetching the logs of DB2 container.

```
- |
      DB2_CONTAINER_ID=$(docker ps | grep "ibmcom/db2:11.5.5.0" | awk '{print $1}')
      echo "Fetching DB2 logs for debugging:"
      docker logs $DB2_CONTAINER_ID
```

However, I received the next error:

> /bin/sh: eval: line 143: docker: not found

which indicates that the Docker command-line interface (CLI) is not available in the environment where the GitLab runner is executing the job. Unfortunately I don't have access to the config.toml file of my GitLab runner, as of now.

6. After further research, I found out that the DB2 needed extra privileges. So I reached the team that manages the runner and they added `privileged = true` into `config.toml`. After this approach the following errors appeared:

> SQL1032N No start database manager command was issued

> SQL1042C An unexpected system error occurred

> SQL1031N The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system

Currently, I am in confusion about what I am doing wrong. Any help and suggestions are much appreciated.